# How to read columns of .txt data with pandas and feed to TF

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

I have a file birth_life_data.txt with the format as:

```
Country fertiliy_rate Life_span 
India 5.7 52
USA 10.2 70
...
...
```

I want to store the fertiliy_rate data in the variable X, and life_span similarly in Y as 1-d arrays, to fed as training data in my TF graph.

How do i use pandas to parse this data and store it in the form of a python array?

Comment: df = pd.read_csv('birth_life_data.txt,sep=' ') ,use pandas read csv specifying seperation by space(' ')

Comment: so df will be a 2-d python array? thanks for the reply :)

Comment: it will be a pandas dataframe , if you take the df.values it will convert to 3 dimensional array with mentioning the Country values also in one columns, if you want to feed it to TF , you may need to encode or exclude the Country columns

Comment: `pandas` has a very flexible file reader [`pd.read_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html). In this case, you can probably get by with `df = pd.read_table('birth_life_data.txt', sep = '\s', engine='python')`

Comment: Is this a tensorflow question ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [read_table()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html) function in pandas to read a text file.

```
df = pd.read_table('birth_life_data.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
```

You can then use the inbuilt list() function to convert them to python arrays.

```
X = list(df['Country'])
Y = list(df['Life_span'])
```